# Adding twitter into PHP form in CMS

Tags: php, model-view-controller, twitter, content-management-system, authorize

Hello I have all sorts of tutorials for authenticating with oAuth, but it seems like everyone else has one piece of the puzzle that I don't.

In my CMS I am editing the controller, where info gets processed on the submit button. `$_POST` contains this data and is simply evaluated for content

```
if(!empty($_POST))
        {
            $mingurl = 'http://www.myurl.com';
            $mingmsg = "New tweet! Link: " . $mingurl;

            //Connect to Twitter
            $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);

            $connection->getAuthorizeURL(OAUTH_TOKEN, true);

            // Posten
            $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $mingmsg));

            // Error afhandeling
            $httpc = $connection->http_code;
            if($httpc == 200) {
                echo 'Tweet posted!';
            } else {
                echo "Failed!";
            } 

        }
```

Now it seems that nothing happened, especially given that the twitter account is not updated. I notice that nowhere here do I call other twitteroauth functions, such as the one that should initially login and allow the twitter application to edit things, but NO tutorial details how this should work. What functions should I call, I am using Abraham Williams twitter oauth php object.

Also I'm not sure if I need to edit the model or view just to add these behind the scenes updating, but I wonder about the popup to add your twitter credentials the first time, would this need to be a feature of the view? How would I call that from the controller etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first get the request token and then actually use the authorize URL for the authentication.

```
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken($callback_url);

$url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
header('Location: '.$url);
```

I can't remember why exactly but for some reason I could use the library you are using right now and created my own: http://code.google.com/p/social-php/

You could also consider to use the 'standard' tweet button if that is more suitable:
http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

Comment: hm the tweet button looks interesting, I want a tweet to be automatically sent with this form. one recurring issue I have in understanding this: my callback url for this twitter app is none, what do I put in the callback url field?

Comment: with your API the oath library adding might be outside of the permissions I have on this server. whereas the other oauth I was using just was some includes to a separate file in the same folder

Comment: If you use php to authorize an account to send a tweet, you'll need a callback url. The user will be send to the twitter site for authentication and then passed back to your site with tokens you'll need. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq

Comment: if that is the site you will use to catch the post variables of twitter, yes. Otherwise www.mysite.com/kickback.php or something like that.

Comment: yes but I dont understand what the contents of "kickback.php" would be, can you elaborate further? I've seen similar callback.php's mentioned in other tutorials but I dont understand their contents